# vc++ file type won't go away

Tags: visual-c++, file-extension

I uninstalled Visual C++ (on Windows XP), but my c++ source files still have the VCExpress.cpp.9.0 extension (when I right click a file and go to properties it shows that as the file type).

How can I change it to what I had originally which was just the CPP type.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In WinXP most comfortably via the folder options in any explorer window:
 Tools -> Folder Options -> File Types

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. Though in Tools -> Folder Options -> File Types it was showing that the cpp extension is a cpp file (there was no mention of VCExpress.cpp.9.0), but from there there was a Restore button that fixed the problem. Thank you again.